# How do I add trigger to an AWS Lambda function using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-lambda

Any way of doing this using AWS CLI?
[image: Adding trigger using AWS Management Console]

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39514119/426790). It can be done using `aws lambda add-permissions`...!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only event sources that are managed within lambda's own cli api are Kinesis Streams and DynamoDb Streams.  You can manage them with the cli using [`aws lambda`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html)

S3 bucket events are managed within S3, as they can be sent to SNS topics, SQS queues, or Lambda functions.  So you need to use the `aws s3api` cli commands, specifically [`put-bucket-notification-configuration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html)

In the `--notification-configuration` arg, you'll have something like:

```
{
  "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
    {
      "Id": "string",
      "LambdaFunctionArn": "string",
      "Events": [events]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where events are list of s3 [events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations)

Comment: uh - kind of missing an example/detail about how to do that with `aws lambda` - `aws lambda help` provides none either.....  ah, the link to `aws lambda` is the clue.   `aws lambda create-event-source-mapping`

Answer (score 10):

I was able to add SNS trigger for lambda using below AWS CLI

```
aws lambda add-permission \
  --function-name {{LAMBDA-FUNCTION-NAME}} \
  --statement-id {{UNIQUE-ID}} \
  --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
  --principal sns.amazonaws.com \
  --source-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:77889900:{{SNS-TOPIC-ARN}}
```

The SNS topic can also be from other region.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

As @user1292364 mentioned we need to use add-permission to the lambda.

Only issue with it is that you need to make sure that *lambda to sns subscription is added als*o. Otherwise this error will occur

```
A subscription for arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:276xxxxxx:function:HourlyLambdaFunction on the topic HourlyLambdaFunction could not be found.
```

I would prefer to use it over AWS CLI in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Add Lambda to SNS as subscription
aws sns subscribe \
    --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:276xxxxxx:HourlyLambdaFunction \
    --protocol lambda \
    --notification-endpoint arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:276xxxxxx:function:HourlyLambdaFunction

# Give permissions to Lambda to access that subscription i.e. Add it through triggers
aws lambda add-permission \
    --function-name HourlyLambdaFunction \
    --statement-id 276xxxxxx\
    --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
    --principal sns.amazonaws.com \
    --source-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:276xxxxxx:HourlyLambdaFunction

# Send message to publish and trigger lamda
aws sns publish \
    --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:276xxxxxx:HourlyLambdaFunction \
    --subject "HourlyLambdaFunction" \
    --message "{datawarehouse:banana_wh, database:banana_db, schema:banana. query:'select count(*) from banana.banana_loads;'}"
```

ps: \ in the code is new line for bash script (if anyone wonders)

*Logs of the lambda function can be found on Cloudwatch*